# Convert numeric values to feet and inches in UI Slider

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I have implemented a slider for height in my application.

[image]

When I slide the min and max values, it will go up to 0.9 and on to 1.0 because it's a decimal value. I want it to go up to 0.11 and at 0.12 it will convert to 1.0, because I want height in feet and inches.(1 Feet = 12 inches).

I have implemented knockoutjs for it as below :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.TwoSideSlider = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
            var sliderValues = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (sliderValues.min !== undefined) {
                options.range = true;
            }

            options.slide = function (e, ui) {
                if (sliderValues.min) {
                    console.log(ui.values[0]);
                    sliderValues.min(ui.values[0]);
                    sliderValues.max(ui.values[1]);
                } else {
                    sliderValues.value(ui.value);
                }
            };

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).slider("destroy");
            });

            $(element).slider(options);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var sliderValues = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());
            if (sliderValues.min !== undefined) {
                $(element).slider("values", [sliderValues.min, sliderValues.max]);
            } else {
                $(element).slider("value", sliderValues.value);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

And my Html Code is :

```
 <div class="slider-control">
        <div data-bind="TwoSideSlider: { min: MinHeight, max: MaxHeight }, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 15, step: 0.1}"></div>
        <div style="top:-12px;" data-bind="TwoSideSlider: { value: MaxHeight }, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 15, step: 0.1}"></div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with this code? It's not clear from description, what exact problem do you have.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal values are base 10, so you won't be able to do what you are trying to do without writing some custom code to convert decimal values to feet and inches.

So ideally, you need **1.5 to equal 1ft 6in**.

If you use [computed values](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) based on an observable, you can just perform simple maths to convert the values for you when the slider moves. For example you can get feet and inches from 1.5 like so:

```
// Round 1.5 down to nearest whole number
Math.floor(1.5); // would return 1 (feet)

// Take the value after decimal point, multiply by 12 & round to a whole number
Math.round(((1.5) % 1) * 12); // would return 0.5 * 12 = 6 (inches)
```

Integrating that in to a computed is demonstrated on the snippet below:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
    var observable = valueAccessor();

    if (observable().splice) {
      options.range = true;
    }

    options.slide = function(e, ui) {
      observable(ui.values ? ui.values : ui.value);
    };

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).slider("destroy");
    });

    $(element).slider(options);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).slider(value.slice ? "values" : "value", value);

  }
};

ViewModel = function() {
  this.values = ko.observable([1.9, 15.0]);
  this.valuesJson = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJSON({
      values: this.values
    });
  }, this);
  this.firstFeet = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.floor(this.values().slice(0, 1));
  }, this);
  this.firstInches = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.round(((this.values().slice(0, 1)) % 1) * 12);
  }, this);
  this.lastFeet = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.floor(this.values().slice(1, 2));
  }, this);
  this.lastInches = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.round(((this.values().slice(1, 2)) % 1) * 12);
  }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.slider {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="slider" data-bind="slider: values, sliderOptions: {min: 1.0, max: 15.0, step: 0.05}"></div>

<span data-bind="text: valuesJson"></span>

<hr />

<p>Min: <span data-bind="text: firstFeet"></span>ft
  <span data-bind="text: firstInches"></span>in</p>
<p>Max: <span data-bind="text: lastFeet"></span>ft
  <span data-bind="text: lastInches"></span>in</p>

<hr />

<p>Min: <span data-bind="text: firstFeet"></span>.<span data-bind="text: firstInches"></span>
</p>
<p>Max: <span data-bind="text: lastFeet"></span>.<span data-bind="text: lastInches"></span>
</p>
```